# Formatting Button Position with Form_For

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I am using form_for to create a form that has 1 input field and 1 button.  I'd like the submit button to be beside the input field rather than underneath it.

Relevant code is:

```
.input{border: 1px solid #666666; width:400px; height:22px;font-size:16px;}

<td width="900" height="50" align="left" valign="middle">
    <% form_for @contact, :url => {:action => "create"}, :html => {:class => "input"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :size=> 74 %>
        <%= image_submit_tag '2009-12-06-Landing1.gif' %>   
    <% end %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
display: inline;
```